# What are the benefits of ASP.NET Web API over ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I frequency experience that Web API has some limitations and some disadvantages that not exists in "ASP.NET MVC".

For instance, ASP.NET Web API doesn't support [OutputCache] attribute "Out of the box" so i had to install NuGet add-on for supporting it.

My question is, why should i choose to work with ASP.NET Web API if i can choose ASP.NET MVC that as far as i know can do whatever WEB API can do and even more?

Comment: If you can't see a use for it, no one (so far as I'm aware) is forcing you to use it. One strong point for it is content negotiation and the corresponding formatter infrastructure.

Answer (score 9):

ASP.NET MVC is an MVC framework for building web aplications. ASP.NET Web API is a framework for building RESTful services. That's the main difference of the two frameworks. They have been built for different purposes and they should be used for the purpose they have been built.

A comparison between ASP.NET Web API and WCF would have been more reasonable, because both are used for the implementaion of SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) solutions. On the other hand, I don't think that we should relate ASP.NET Web API with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i know that but as far as i understand, ASP.NET MVC also support RESTful, Isn't it?

Comment: You welcome. When you say that ASP.NET MVC supports RESTful what do you mean? ASP.NET MVC uses the MVC pattern for building web apps. There are controllers listen for requests. The controllers when receive a request using the Model and the Views associated with them build an http response, which subsequently it is sent to the browser of the client for rendering. Why we should use ASP.NET MVC for covering service oriented solutions (like RESTful), while it's creation purpose is totally different?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios Why do you think that RESTful systems are focused on building service oriented solutions?  The reality is that most HTML based web sites follow more of the REST constraints than most Web APIs.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Shouldn't we consider a service that is used from a web application or some other application a service oriented solution to a specific problem?  I get your argument regarding the RESTful systems and SO solutions. For that reason I will delete my previous comment and probably I will rewrite it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC is optimized to return content to a web browser over HTTP and is based on the ASP.NET runtime (system.web) that has been around for > 10 years.

ASP.NET Web API is a HTTP application framework that does not care what client you are serving.  It is built on a new Http stack that can be used for both the client and server side.

Both frameworks can produce RESTful applications, neither are particularly optimized for it.

Comment: Could you please share some examples of something i can't do with the traditional MVC and can do with the Web API?

Comment: @Omtechguy Run as a Windows Service, as a console app, with an in-memory host.

Comment: @Omtechguy Web Api also supports OData

Answer (score 1):

MVC is a framework for develop web application but Web api is for develop REST service. we can compair WebAPI with Wcf because both are for develop for services.

when we use WebApi then we no need to add attribute on method like Get,Put etc but we have to make method name start with GetEmployee,PutEmployee,PostEmployee etc..

authentication is more simple 
we can authenticate user at entry point of the service,no need to authenticate at every method or controller. only 
we have to add "Authenticate" attribute on method or controller as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i still do not understand why to not use MVC also for WEBApi services. its richer then the WEBAPI. Could you please explain?